# Failed to login using Google play game services sdk

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I am trying to implement Google sign in using Google play game services SDK in my unity 3d game.

Trying to login opens a dialog with my app name and Icon following a green circular loading bar and then the dialog disappears with the following error message.

```
    2019-04-23 00:48:05.328 30039-30101/? D/TokenFragment: signIn
    2019-04-23 00:48:05.328 30039-30101/? D/TokenFragment: signInClient.silentSignIn
    2019-04-23 00:48:05.673 30039-30039/? D/TokenFragment: silentSignIn.onFailure
    2019-04-23 00:48:05.691 1439-5286/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: not whiteListed <Package_Name>/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity/46
    2019-04-23 00:48:05.692 1439-5286/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListed <Package_Name>/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity/46
    2019-04-23 00:48:05.742 1439-5286/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListed <Package_Name>/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity/46
    2019-04-23 00:48:05.753 1439-3235/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: not whiteListedcom.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.ui.SignInActivity/16089021
    2019-04-23 00:48:05.753 1439-3235/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.ui.SignInActivity/16089021
    2019-04-23 00:48:05.765 1439-5286/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.ui.SignInActivity/16089021
    2019-04-23 00:48:05.839 1439-1576/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.google.android.gms/.auth.api.signin.ui.SignInActivity: +63ms (total +86ms)
    2019-04-23 00:48:05.840 4044-4212/? D/PowerKeeper.Event: notifyActivityLaunchTime: com.google.android.gms/.auth.api.signin.ui.SignInActivity totalTime: 86
    2019-04-23 00:48:06.108 1439-3230/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: not whiteListedcom.google.android.play.games/com.google.android.gms.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity/90780048
    2019-04-23 00:48:06.109 1439-3230/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.google.android.play.games/com.google.android.gms.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity/90780048
    2019-04-23 00:48:06.130 1439-5288/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.google.android.play.games/com.google.android.gms.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity/90780048
    2019-04-23 00:48:06.202 30445-30445/? I/SignInActivity: Transition from -1 to 0
    2019-04-23 00:48:06.316 797-797/? D/SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name: changing com.google.android.play.games/com.google.android.gms.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity to com.google.android.play.games/com.google.android.gms.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity#1
    2019-04-23 00:48:06.401 1439-1576/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.google.android.play.games/com.google.android.gms.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity: +250ms (total +295ms)
    2019-04-23 00:48:06.401 4044-4212/? D/PowerKeeper.Event: notifyActivityLaunchTime: com.google.android.play.games/com.google.android.gms.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity totalTime: 295
    2019-04-23 00:48:09.898 30445-30445/? E/ViewRootImpl[SignInActivity]: Attempting to destroy the window while drawing!
          window=android.view.ViewRootImpl@b627327, title=com.google.android.play.games/com.google.android.gms.games.ui.signin.SignInActivity
    2019-04-23 00:48:09.931 30445-30445/? I/SignInActivity: Transition from 0 to 1
    2019-04-23 00:48:09.946 30445-30445/? I/SignInActivity: Transition from 1 to 3
    2019-04-23 00:48:10.012 30445-30445/? I/SignInActivity: Transition from 3 to 4
    2019-04-23 00:48:10.596 30445-30445/? I/SignInActivity: Transition from 4 to 5
    2019-04-23 00:48:10.622 30445-30445/? I/SignInActivity: Transition from 5 to 6
    2019-04-23 00:48:10.975 30445-30445/? I/SignInActivity: Transition from 6 to 11
    2019-04-23 00:48:10.975 30445-30445/? W/SignInActivity: onSignInFailed()...
    2019-04-23 00:48:10.975 30445-30445/? W/SignInActivity: Sign in failed during 6
    2019-04-23 00:48:10.975 30445-30445/? W/SignInActivity: ==> Returning non-OK result: 10002
    2019-04-23 00:48:11.056 1439-1449/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.ui.SignInActivity/16089021
    2019-04-23 00:48:11.057 1439-1449/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedcom.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.ui.SignInActivity/16089021
    2019-04-23 00:48:11.127 1439-5294/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListed <Package_Name>/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity/46
    2019-04-23 00:48:11.127 1439-5294/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListed <Package_Name>/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity/46
```

Here is the code trying to sign in.

```
void Start()
{
    Instance = this;

    PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder().Build();
    PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
    // recommended for debugging:
    PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
    // Activate the Google Play Games platform
    PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    signIn();
}

public void signIn()
{
    Debug.Log("sigining in");
    Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
    {
        if (success)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("signin", 1);
            isLoggedIn = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isLoggedIn = false;
        }
    });
}
```

I have already done:

1. Checking Package name of the application
2. Checking SHA-1 signing-certificate fingerprint
3. I have added myself as a tester in play console.
4. I have published app in closed alpha me as a tester.

I have not published this app in Game services, but its in "Ready to publish" state with my account as test account.

Comment: had similar issue today, and what seems to have resolved it was going to the corresponding app project at Google API console, and filling in & submitting the OAuth consent screen for verification and fixing all of the warnings around credentials (limiting access token's to a certain platform). Not sure which of these 2 fixed the problem, I did them both at once.  Reading this post helped - https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/2362